# Open SSL error in unix :oaep decoding error

Tags: linux, perl, rsa, ssh-keys

We have a shell script command where it transfer the files from one server to other. While the command is getting executed we are facing below error

We are facing below error

```
Error: RSA.xs:202: OpenSSL error: oaep decoding error at /File.m line 40
```

If any one has any idea please suggest..

Comment: While there are no useful details apart from the error message I suggest that [RSA encrypt then decrypt fails with "oaep decoding error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222068/rsa-encrypt-then-decrypt-fails-with-oaep-decoding-error) might describe the same problem you have and offers a solution.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich.. Thanks a lot for the reply, But i am not able to understand the content like why we face this issue ?

Comment: I can only speculate due to a lack of any details: wrong input into a program. To cite from the answer to the other question: *"public key does not match the private key"*.